# Is it possible to vertically auto-center an element within a div?

Tags: css, margin

I’ve got an online photo gallery. The thumbnail page is a grid of 150px x 150px divs, the thumbnail images are set inside them.

Since the thumbnail images are rectangular, the ideal thing would be to auto-center them inside the divs.

Reading here, I’ve figured out how to center them horizontally. I’ve also been reading that auto-centering vertically isn’t possible until CSS3 takes off. Is this true?

I've gotten the horizontal images to auto center with this:

```
.portrait_t {
width: auto;
height: 150px;
text-align: center;
display: block;
margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
}
```

But, the vertical centering doesn't work with this:

```
.landscape_t {
width: 150px;
height: auto;
display: block;
margin: auto 0 auto 0;
}
```

If there's just no way to do this until CSS3 then I'll have to come up with a workaround, but if I'm missing something, please let me know.

Thank you all in advance for your help!

Comment: Please [don't add signatures or taglines to your posts](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures).

Comment: If this is just a CSS question, why are you talking about PHP and MySQL? Cut the chaff, get to the point.

Comment: There are way, way too many words in your question, wordman. Questions are not correspondence, and they are not forum posts, and anything that isn't actually relevant to the question you're asking should be pared away to make your question as succinct as possible.

Comment: @ Matt Ball So sorry. I was meaning to be thorough.

Comment: @ meagar My apologies. Noted.

Comment: @ hakre well, it was trimmed down for me, the jist of the problem remains in the text. I apologize for the errors of my ways, I'm still new here. If I understand you correctly, you're looking for the HTML as well.

Comment: text-align: center; margin: 0 auto;   that should take care of your problems.

Comment: @Tony318 It doesn't for vertical alignment though.

Comment: @wordman Vertical alignment is very difficult and there isn't usually an easy solution. Your best bet would probably be to use padding-top: ?px; and play around with the pixels until it looks right.

Comment: @Tony318 Actually, hakre proposed the solution that worked perfectly. My requirement was dealing with images of varying sizes, not one specific size which necessitated getting away from the hard coding I was using. Check out hakre's solution below. It works perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an inline element (the `<img>`) that is inside a sized parent `<div>` element:

```
<div>
    <img />
</div>
```

All you need to do is to make it center and middle aligned. You center it with `text-align:center;` in the parent `<div>` and you middle align it by giving the `<div>` the `line-height` of it's full height. Additionally, as it's an `<img>` tag you give that image tag the `vertical-align:middle;` that done it's in there, regardless of it's own size:

[image]

Example/[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fw4MA/):

```
<style>
div {width:350px; height:350px; line-height:350px; text-align:center;}
  div img {vertical-align:middle;}​
</style>

<div>
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/PKnWs.jpg">
</div>
<div>
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/Az6NUl.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: many thanks for the through explanation. I'm still missing something here though. I amended your code to my page:

`.thumb {
 float:left;
 width: 150px;
 height: 150px;
 line-height: 150px;
 text-align: center;
 background-color: #333333;
 margin:10px 10px 10px 10px;
 border: 1px solid #afafaf;
 border-radius: 10px;
}

img.tn {
 vertical-align: middle;
}`

It still centers horizontally but not vertically.

Comment: @wordman: You must have made an error somewhere, that problem is not related to the code here: http://jsfiddle.net/fw4MA/2/

Comment: I'm stumped. I did it a little different and made an `img` class: `img.tn { vertical-align: middle; }` as opposed to calling it out as you did. I have image classes elsewhere that work though.

Comment: I created a test page and pasted in the code you provided verbatim. The images are centered horizontally but not vertically. http://g490.com/test.html

Comment: You are probably running into some quirk more or so. Consider using this doctype: `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict/EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">`

Comment: That did the trick! I was using the transitional doctype: `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">' It also works with the HTML5 doctype as well.

Comment: That brings you into standards mode, and that is what you want.

Comment: As a closing note, I wanted to share this bit. my `.thumb' div is 150px x 150px. Setting the `line-height` at 150px was forcing the images downward a few pixels. I ended up changing the `line-height` to 146px and the thumbs now look perfect. Any idea what caused this? And thank you so much for your help, I appreciate you staying with me on this!

Comment: you have got a 1px border on each side, so probably the line-height is 148px to make this perfect. Also you have whitespace around the image which might reposition the image a bit. See as well http://www.cssdesignpatterns.com/Chapter%2009%20-%20POSITIONING3/Middle%20Aligned/example.html

Comment: I thought the border would have been the culprit, but I had to take 4px out as opposed to just 2 as 148px didn't work. As you can see I'm flying by the seat of my pants here, where is the whitespace you're mentioning...or is it the empty `.thumb' div?

Comment: hmm. perhaps a browser bug because of the float or something, or the whitespace. you might need to play around a bit to find out what exactly is going on. Which pixel-sizes do the graphics have?

Comment: Currently there are two sizes, 150 x 118 and 150 x 100. I'm going to keep it to where the number of different sizes is minimal. The `line-height` of `146px` works for both thumbnail sizes though. I love this technique you showed me because it makes the code more flexible.